# Perforce (p4) sync maxresults error

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am getting below error when trying to sync:

> Request too large (over 110000); see 'p4 help maxresults'

Because of the above error, I am not able to sync.
Can you please let me know how to increase the `maxresults` to unlimited or if there is any other way to handle this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @MatthewD: I'm sorry, but 'please post your code' is not sensible; it requires a P4 repository (depot) and its history.  It's like asking someone "post your complete .git directory".

Comment: What does `p4 help maxresults` say?  I don't have access to Perforce, but I've used a system derived from it.  That system used 'clients', and you'd sync your client with the repository (depot).  When did you create your client?  Why have you got over 100k changes to sync?  Can you make a series of smaller sync operations, syncing to changelists 10k apart instead of needing more than 100k all at once?

Comment: @jonathan leffler, I did in smaller chunks and it worked and also asked my perforce admin to increase the maxresults and its working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Your resource limits are associated with your username based on which group(s) your user is included in.

From 'p4 help group':

```
Each group has MaxResults, MaxScanRows, and MaxLockTime fields,
which limit the resources committed to operations performed by
members of the group.  For these fields, 'unlimited' or 'unset'
means no limit for that group.  An individual user's limit is the
highest of any group with a limit to which he belongs, unlimited if
any of his groups has 'unlimited' for that field, or unlimited
if he belongs to no group with a limit.  See 'p4 help maxresults'
for more information on MaxResults, MaxScanRows and MaxLockTime.
```

So your administrator can place your userid into an alternate group, with a higher set of resource limits, which will then allow you to use more server resources.

Alternatively, you can sync fewer files. For example, you could edit your client spec to specify a smaller portion of the depot in your View:, or you could specify a smaller set of files to sync, rather than syncing your entire workspace.

In my workspaces, I try to specify the smallest set of files which will allow me to do my job; a workspace with a View like:

```
View:
    //depot/branch/my/project/... //client/my/project/...
```

is going to result in a smaller sync than a workspace with a View like:

```
View:
    //depot/... //client/...
```